# Mod-rewrite Port in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm playing with home assistant (HA) in docker on Ubuntu 20.04. HA is hosted on port 8123. HA does not support subpaths, ie. it is hosted at `MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:8123` rather than `MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:8123/ha`. I would like it to be reachable via `MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org/ha`. I think I need to use mod-rewrite to accomplish this but I'm not sure. Apache is running on main OS. Any help would be much appreciated.

PS. I know have port forwarding and dyn dns working because I can currently reach the site via `MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:8123`. I also have other services that support subpaths reachable using `ProxyPass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redirecting `MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org/ha` to `ha.MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org`

```
<VirtualHost MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:80>
  ServerName MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org
  RedirectMatch /ha/(.*) https://MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:80>
  ServerName ha.MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org
  RedirectMatch /(.*) https://MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:80>
  ServerName MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org
  RedirectMatch /(.*) https://MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName ha.MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org
  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile <FILE>
  SSLCertificateKeyFile <KEYFILE>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests off
  RequestHeader set-X-Forwarded_proto "https"
  ProxyPass / http://ha.MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:8123/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://ha.MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile <ha_FILE>
  SSLCertificateKeyFile <ha_KeyFILE>
  RedirectMatch /ha(.*) https://ha.MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:443$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile <FILE>
  SSLCertificateKeyFile <KeyFILE>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution to avoid the problems with changing the URL base, i.e. from / to /ha.

Answer (score 2):

You need a proxy instead of a rewrite, because you're sending the connection to a different service than Apache.

```
ProxyPass        /ha/ http://MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /ha/ http://MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org:8123/
```

See [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Comment: That was my original thought as well but the site servers content from /auth, /lovelace, /static, etc. They aren't caught by the proxypass. The site loads but only with only the background.

Comment: I think that's a different problem. The content has absolute links in it, that need to be adjusted to start with `/ha`.  For that you need [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).

Comment: You don't know what you don't know... I've never used mod_proxy_html. I'll try it tonight and post back. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. mod_proxy_html may work for you, but it's a fiddly thing, to take the HTML apart, adjust the links, and put it all back together. It's a static analysis, so it can't work on some cases, such as URLs you calculate on the fly in Javascript or CSS.

Comment: @Andew-Schulman what do you think of my answer?